# Error in asp fpdf header using vbscript

Tags: asp-classic, fpdf

I  want to include header image in all the pdf pages created   by fpdf asp version

```
<%@language =vbscript %>
 <!--#include file="fpdf.asp"-->
 <%
Set pdf=CreateJsObject("FPDF")
Pdf.Header = function Header ( ) 
Pdf.image "imgurl ", 2,3,205,12  
End function
pdf.CreatePDF()
pdf.SetPath("fpdf/")
pdf.SetFont "Arial","B",16
pdf.Open()
pdf.AddPage()
pdf.AddPage ()
pdf.Cell 40,10,"Hello, world!"
pdf.Close()
pdf.Output()
 %>

It shows error " syntax error "  at
 pdf.header= function Header ()
```

But when I use

```
<%@language=javascript%>
<%
Var pdf = new FPDF ( );
Pdf.Header = function Header ( )
 {
 Pdf.image ('imgurl ', 2,3,205,12);
 }
 %>
```

It is working perfectly But I have to use vbscript Please help

Comment: please add the relevant code snippet and format the code and error.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the things which you have posted in the comments. It is hard to read it in comments.

Comment: check: [Tutorials - ASP FPDF](https://sites.google.com/site/aspfpdf/tutorials)

Comment: Their is nothing about use of header

Comment: I am generating a pdf using fpdf vbscript every thing was Ok untill I need to put header image on every page created . It is working perfectly when called using language = javascript but I have to use vbscript

Comment: can't you add the image, without using the header?

Comment: No I can add without header but not when calling header , even header works when hard code the header function

Comment: like `Pdf.Header=<imagename>` ? . If so, isn't that enough?

Comment: It shows type mismatch errors at line 8  and it is                           pdf.header= imgurl

Comment: No, i was asking if you were doing it like that when you said `even header works when hard code the header `. What I am saying is, can't you add the image as the header, without actually using the `Pdf.Header` line, like they are doing here: http://thewebthought.blogspot.com/2010/10/asp-create-pdf-files-with-fpdf.html

Comment: Yes I can but it only comes on the first page not on the rest of pages

Comment: Does this help: http://thewebthought.blogspot.com/2010/10/asp-create-pdf-files-with-fpdf.html?showComment=1391535449295#c3972632892684088

Comment: Yes thanks you make my day thanks once again

Comment: Can you please add your solution as an answer, it will be useful for future visitors.

Comment: Can u please tell me how can I

Comment: Enter your existing code in the `Your Answer` section below. And you can select it as the answer by clicking on the tick sign afterwards. Add the link i gave to the answer too.http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
   <script language="javascript" runat="server">
    function redefine(Obj)
    {
        Obj.Header=function Header()
        {
            Obj.Image('header20512.jpg',2,3,205,12);    
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script language="vbscript">
    <!--#include file="fpdf.asp" -->
    <%
    dim pdf
    set pdf=CreateJsObject("FPDF")
    redefine pdf
    pdf.CreatePDF()
    pdf.SetPath("fpdf/")
    pdf.SetFont "Arial","",10
    pdf.Open()
    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.Ln(8)
    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.Ln()
    pdf.Close()
    pdf.Output()
    %>
```